# change theano shared variable do not effect the value of internal

Tags: python, theano

i have a little problem with shared variable.  codes as below:

```
np_array = numpy.ones(2, dtype='float32')
s_true = theano.shared(np_array,borrow=True)
np_array+=1.
print s_true.get_value()#[ 2.  2.] change np_array will change s_true
```

**i can understand the above.  but reverse can't work,as below:**

```
np_array = numpy.ones(2, dtype='float32')
s_true = theano.shared(np_array,borrow=True)
s_true+=1.0
print s_true.eval()   #[ 2.  2.]
np_array  #array([ 1.,  1.], dtype=float32) **change s_true will not change np_array**
```

**however,the below work:**

```
s_true = theano.shared(np_array,borrow=True)
v_true=s_true.get_value(borrow=True,return_internal_type=True)
v_true+=1.0
print s_true.get_value() #[ 2.  2.] **change v_true will change s_true**  
np_array #array([ 2.,  2.], dtype=float32) **change v_true will change np_array**
```

i cannot understand the logic of shared variable, hope to get help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answered on [theano-users mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/theano-users/HpBQcLgsmbE).

A shared variable wraps a piece of memory but there is no guarantee that only the piece of memory used to initialize the shared variable will be used throughout the computation.

`borrow=True` should be thought of as a hint rather than an explicit instruction to be followed in all cases.

In the first example the shared variable wraps the initial numpy array because `borrow=True`. Changing the numpy array thus changes the contents of the shared variable. But this should not be relied upon and is poor practice for Theano programming.

In the second example `s_true+=1.0` is a symbolic expression. It does not actually change any state in memory other than making `s_true` point at an object representing the expression rather than the shared variable. `print s_true.eval()` shows the result of executing the symbolic computation but that does not change the shared variable. The only "approved" ways to change the contents of a shared variable are via `shared_var.set_value(...)` or via the `updates=...` mechanism of `theano.function(...)`. Changing the backing store, as in the first example, will sometimes work but not always and should generally be avoided.

The third example is just a more roundabout way of doing the first example so is again bad practice.

[This page in the documentation](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/tutorial/aliasing.html) may help.

Comment: i am a new theano-user,so just thought that "+=" will change shared variable. now i know the appropriate way to change shared variables is via set_value or updates.  **but i found that even i use set_value or updates to change s_true, it won't change the value of the internal storage(np_array)**. so when s_true wraps np_array, what actually do behind this operation. isn't   s_true act like reference to np_array?

Comment: You should forget about the original numpy array once it has been wrapped by a Theano shared variable. There is absolutely no guarantee they point to the same bit of memory. (1) create initial value numpy array, (2) give initial value to Theano shared variable, (3) forget there was ever any link between the initial value numpy array and the Theano shared variable, (4) update shared variable, (5) get updated value via get_value().